# The relation between Gromov hausdorff convergence and inverse limit of compact metric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The relation between Gromov hausdorff convergence and inverse limit of compact metric spaces.

Comment: Gromov-Hausdorff convergence makes sense in the "space" of compact metric spaces *up to isometry*. So "being in a Euclidean space" does not make much sense her.

Comment: The question could be rephrased as follows: Does there exist a subset of Euclidean space that is isometric to the Gromov-Hausdorff limit?

Comment: I simply feel that the question should be more specific, more precise. (I'd have some suggestions but it's a task for the one who poses the question).